# python : Split string separated by a pipe symbol "|"

Tags: python, split, pipe

Have a look at the following string:

```
E|1256280||2014-01-05 17:54:00|1|2014-01-05 18:59:53|True
```

I'd like to split it wrt. the pipe symbol "|". Therefore I use the following python code (where line is a string containing the described string above):

```
                print line
                print str(type(line))
                print str(line[1])
                parts = line.split['|']
                print str(parts)
```

However, when using this piece of code i get the following error:

```
E|1256280||2014-01-05 17:54:00|1|2014-01-05 18:59:53|True
<type 'str'>
|
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/pythonscritp.py", line 34, in crawl_live_quotes
    parts = line.split['|']
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

However, I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need `()` not `[]`

Comment: `str.split` is a function. You call functions with parentheses, not square brackets.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The

```
parts = line.split['|']
```

should be

```
parts = line.split('|')
```

(i.e. with parentheses instead of square brackets.)

Answer (score 4):

To *call* a method, use `()` around the arguments:

```
parts = line.split('|')
```

not `[]`, which is the syntax for sequence indexing.

I'd use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead, configuring the reader with the `|` character as the delimiter:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

will handle splitting for you.